# User access in Jenkins, How can I give someone access to only see jobs

Tags: jenkins

User access in Jenkins, How can I give someone access to only see jobs.

I want to setup a admin and everyone else can only see jobs.  can someone please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Jenkins Wiki has a good explanation of how this is done: [Standard Security Setup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup).

Essentially you do this:

- Go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security.
- Check "Enable security".
- Set "Jenkins own user database" as security realm.
- Check "Allow users to sign up"
- Choose "Matrix based security"
- Check "Overall read" on Anonymous.
- Add your admin account in the matrix, check every box.
- Save configuration and sign up with the admin username to set a password.

Comment: Now "Enable security", "Jenkins own user database" etc is under "Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security" menu.

Comment: Hi, How does this address the issue of jobs with hard coded user creds in them? Jenkins matrix based security only allows create, delete, configure, and build perms on jobs. Though technically the original question was just for read only access to see the jobs and not the job configs.

Comment: Good answer. One detail which is missing: this requires 'matrix based security' plugin to be installed already on Jenkins. Right now present as 'matrix authorization strategy' plugin.

Comment: Upvote. Thanks so much for this. Why wouldn't they just move this to a more meaningful place like "Manage Privilege" or something?! I would never check something named security, thinking "I am just a developer, may be sec-ops guys know this" -_-

Answer (score 6):

Go to "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" and under "Authorization" choose "Matrix-based security". You can then configure exactly what each user should be able to do.

Answer (score 6):

One simple way:
I went in Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security and checked **Allow anonymous read access**.

Now any body who doesn't have credentials can view the jobs.

Comment: This is the easiest way to only have one user that can create jobs, etc, and everyone else just has read access

Answer (score 5):

**Steps to create a new user in Jenkins with only READ access**

**Steps to create a new user**

1. Login into Jenkins
2. Go to Manage Jenkins
3. Go to Create Users
4. Enter all the details – Username, Password, Confirm Pwd, FullName, Email
5. Select Create User

**Steps to assign only read access**

1. Login to Jenkins
2. Go to Manage Jenkins
3. Go to Configure Global Security
4. Select Jenkins own User Database
5. Tick the checkbox “Allow Users to Sign Up”
6. Select Matrix-based security
7. Select the button “Add user or group”
8. Write User or Group name – **write the user name of the user you created**
9. Tick 3 read option under – **Overall, Job, View**
10. Save and Apply

**Login with the new user id and check if the changes are reflected**